# How do I get Rails 5.0.6 working on Windows with Ruby 2.4 and Nokogiri 1.8.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I upgraded Ruby from 2.3 to 2.4. When I run bundle, I get

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace>bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.4, >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.7.0.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  nested_form_fields was resolved to 0.8.2, which depends on
    rails was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      actioncable was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
        actionpack was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
          actionview was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
            rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
              nokogiri
```

However, I was able to install Rails manually with `gem install rails --version 5.0.6`. It installed Nokogiri 1.8.1. (I also installed, then removed Rails 5.0.2.)

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace>gem list nokogiri

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

nokogiri (1.8.1 x64-mingw32)
```

However, `bundle` and `rails -v` still won't work.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace>rails -v
Could not find nokogiri-1.7.0.1-x64-mingw32 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
ruby '~> 2.4.0'
...
```

Comment: The error is `Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.4, >= 2.1.0`. Try unlocking the version of `nested_form_fields` and see whether that makes nokogiri resolve to a version that supports ruby 2.4

Comment: Hmm, it's not my project. Here is its [`Gemfile`](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields/blob/master/Gemfile) and [`nested_form_fields.gemspec`](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields/blob/master/nested_form_fields.gemspec). It actually specifies 'nokogiri', '1.6.8.1'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to prove this since the nokogiri team does not release a gemspec, but that version of nokogiri may not support ruby 2.4 on Windows.

Take a look at:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.7.1/.cross_rubies. IT does not include ruby 2.4.x.

If you absolutely need to upgrade to ruby 2.4 try locking nokogiri version on 1.8.1, which seems to support ruby 2.4 on windows as per https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.8.1/.cross_rubies

```
gem 'nokogiri', '1.8.1'
```

Comment: How do you change the `nested_form_fields` dependency? Why do you think it depends on 1.7.0.1?

Comment: Sorry, my assumption was incorrect since nested_form_fields specifies nokogiri as a development dependency, not a runtime dependency. Still I think nokogiri 1.7.1 does not support ruby 2.4 on windows, so you would need to force usage of nokogiri 1.8.1 which does.  Updated the answer.